# Error messege " Invalid Syntax "

Tags: python, syntax-error

I am trying to add Except Error so when someone writes anything except " Sonnig" "Niedrig" "Stark " "Schwach" "Regnerig"

So I was trying few days to add error message instead of red error message

```
def wetter():
    print()
    print("Fahrradwetter")
    print()
    wetter = str(input("Bitte geben Sie Wetteraussicht ein (sonnig, regnerisch) :"))
    luft = str(input("Bitte geben Sie Luftfeuchtigkeit ein (hoch, niedrig) :"))
    wind = str(input("Bitte geben Sie Windstarke ein (stark, schwach) :"))

    if wetter == "sonnig" and luft == "niedrig":
        work()
    elif wetter == "sonnig" and luft == "hoch":
        false()
    elif wetter == "regnerisch" and wind == "stark":
        false()
    elif wetter == "regnerisch" and wind == "schwach":
        work()
    else:
        print("Niste tacno uneli")
        wetter()
    except ValueError:
        print ("Bitte wählen sie ein von beiden")

def work():
    print()
    print("~~~!Es ist Fahrradwetter!~~~")
def false():
    print()
    print("~~~!Es ist kein Fahrradwetter!~~~")


wetter()
```

Comment: I added the code.

Comment: We ask that questions have a [mcve] -- the **shortest possible code** that generates the same problem. There's surely much that can be removed while generating the same bug. (We also ask that the specific error or exception be included in the question itself).

Comment: What do you mean by a "red error message"?

Comment: I want to make a script for Wheater, so if a person types anything except the "" Sonnig" "Niedrig" "Stark " "Schwach" "Regnerig"" . then comes error

I want instead error to come a text please type again or something!

Answer (score 0):

Your functions `work()` and `false()` are after the function where they are called. Move them to the top.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, there is:

> ```
> except ValueError:
>     print ("Bitte wählen sie ein von beiden")
> ```

But you cannot have an `except` block without a `try` block before it.

I suggest you simply remove these two lines.

Comment: I want to add if someone types anything except " Sonnig" "Niedrig" "Stark " "Schwach" "Regnerig" "then comes a messege please type right one or something like that and not error msg

Comment: ...so put the code to which the `except` block is intended to apply inside a `try` block above it.